# How to print rows from a list (CSV) using the results of xrange?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to figure out how to print rows from a list using inputed xrange. I'm trying not to abbreviate my code because I'm still learning and want to follow the logic clearly. So what I want is to print a range of rows from the user provided arguments. I know I have some of the order wrong, but I'm stuck on how to type it out... Here is what I have so far:

```
import csv
import sys

sourcef = sys.argv[1]  # Source file path/name
destf = sys.argv[2]  # Destination file path/name
linestart = int(sys.argv[3])  # Starting row to delete
lineend = int(sys.argv[4])  # Ending row to delete

with open (sourcef, 'rb') as file1, open (destf, 'wb') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file1)
    writer = csv.writer(file2)
    row = list(reader)
    for i in xrange(linestart, lineend):
        print i
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What's not working?

Comment: I tried setting the xrange as another variable, then trying.

    print row[variable]

But it didn't like that because it wants int, so I tried setting xrange to int and I got more errors about that. The list method seems to be the simplest for me, people have tried pointing me to other methods of doing this and they were far more complicated. If I can get row[] to print my range I would be golden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a `slice` object not `xrange`:

```
...
rows = list(reader)
for x in rows[slice(linestart, lineend)]:
     print x
```

which is the more verbose form of:

```
...
rows = list(reader)
for x in rows[linestart: lineend]:
     print x
```

You may not need to materialise the `reader` iterator as a list, especially in cases where you only need a small portion of the rows. In that case, you can use `itertools.islice`.

```
from itertools import islice

...
for x in islice(reader, linestart, lineend)
     print x
```

Comment: YES!!!! Thank you, I've been hammering away at this parsing script for days. I'm very slow at learning programming languages and tried to find the answers myself reading documentation and Stackoverflow. Wow, that worked so well. Thanks! @moseskoledoye

Comment: @DevinSt.Clair You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: My apologies for the delay, it locked me from setting your answer as the accepted answer for several minutes then I had to leave work. Thanks again, that really helped me under that missing piece and it excites me to write more.